# Highlight posts that belong to current sub category

Tags: categories

I'm trying to highlight list items that belong to the same category as that of the current category page.

For an example, I have a category called *food*, with the subcategories: *breakfast*, *lunch* and *dinner*. If you navigate to the sub-category *lunch* – in a loop that calls all posts regardless of category – I want all list items that are associated to *lunch*, to be highlighted.

Firstly I use `get_category` and `->term_id` to define the ID of the category we're currently on. Secondly, in the loop, I use `get_the_category` and `[0]->cat_ID` to retrieve the ID (but only the first in the array) of each individual list item. Lastly, I use `in_array` to see if there is a match between the two arguments, and if so echo a value.

My problems lies in the `$categories[0]->cat_ID`. If a list item is associated to more than one category, retrieving only the first one in the array is no good.

How do I create an argument that will output all category IDs associated with a list item in a loop?

```
<?php
$thisTrueCat = get_category( get_query_var( 'cat' ) ); 
?>


<!-- loop start -->

<?php 
$categories = get_the_category(); 
$categories_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;            
?>


<?php if( in_array( $thisTrueCat->term_id, array($categories_id) ) ) { echo 'cat-hi'; }?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
$categories = get_the_category(); 
$categories_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
```

...use:

```
$categories = wp_list_pluck( get_the_category(), 'term_id' );
```

Now you can correctly use `in_array` to search all the post's categories, rather than just the first:

```
if ( in_array( $thisTrueCat->term_id, $categories ) )  { ... }
```